# How to Multithread reading, processing and writing data in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am relatively new to Qt and C++ and completely self-taught. I'm trying to multi-thread a task which I currently have working on a single thread.

My task is as follows:

1. Read in multiple csv files line by line and store each column of data from each file into separate vectors.
2. Process the index of each vector of data through various mathematical equations.
3. Once each index of data is processed, write the results of the equations to an output file.

Example file being read in:

```
Col1,   Col2,   Col3,   Col4,  . . .  ColN
1,      A,      B,      C,     . . .  X
2,      D,      E,      F,     . . .  Y
3,      G,      H,      J,     . . .  Z
.,      .,      .,      .,     . . .  .
.,      .,      .,      .,     . . .  .
N,      .,      .,      .,     . . .  .
```

And here is some sudo code showing the principle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1)
{
    // there are multiple nested for loops, but only one shown here

    // calculate multiple variables. Here are two examples:
    calculatedVariable = Col2[i] + Col3[i] / Col4 [i];
    calculatedVariable2 = (Col2[i] * 0.98) / (Col2[i] + Col3[i] + Col4[i]) + (Col2[i] + Col3[i])
    
    // then write the calculated variables to an output text file
    output << calculatedVariable << "," << calculatedVariable2 << std::endl;
}
```

This works great as the code writes to the output text file at the end of each loop iteration, and so it doesn't clog up RAM (i.e. instead of doing all computations, storing in vectors and then writing the data out all in one go).

My problem is that these files can have hundreds of thousands of lines and processing can take a couple of hours. If I can multi-thread, such that the ***processing*** is carried out for multiple indices of data simultaneously, while maintaining the order of data in the output file, it would drastically reduce computation time. I don't need to multi-thread the reading of data at this stage.

I am currently struggling at the conceptual aspect of tackling this and can't find any similar examples online. I've look at QtConcurrent as an option but not quite sure how to apply it.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** Thanks for the responses. So the bottle-neck is the actual processing of the data through some long iterative calculations, not the IO operations. Lets say I read 2 files, each with 1000 lines. If I want to run some calculations for each line in file 1 for each line in file 2, that's 1,000,000 cases. If there was some way to split the task of those calculations across lets say 10 threads, that would cut processing time massively.

Comment: Looks like the bottle neck are IO operations. I recommend you to come back to single thread version and profile it to locate where the actual problem is. Multiple threads will not give a great boost if problem is IO operations.

Comment: Lot of stuff in there to cover making this question overly broad. All that can be said is parallelize that which can be parallelized and get creative with the rest. Make sure you profile everything to prove that your work has actually made things better. Many people toss threads at stuff expecting magic, and find the cost of thread and contention management actually slowed them down.

Comment: The parsing step may be inefficient (frequen for CSV file computations), but using CSV is a poor choice in the first place. This data format is not efficient nor robust. It is only good for small files because it can be easily read by humans. You can parse a CSV in parallel but this is not trivial. Without more infos on the hardware nor profiling infos we cannot know which part is the bottleneck and most of us will not invest a lot of time in trying to solve a problem that may not exist (or may not be solvable) in the first place. Btw, the heart of the problem is quite independent of Qt.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So the bottle-neck is the actual processing of the data through some long iterative calculations, not the IO operations. Lets say I read 2 files, each with 1000 lines. If I want to run some calculations for each line in file 1 for each line in file 2, that's 1,000,000 cases. If there was some way to split the task of those calculations across lets say 10 threads, that would cut processing time massively.

Comment: I'd recommend using the QThreadPool class ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthreadpool.html ) and having your CSV-reader thread(s) create `QRunnable`-subclassed jobs containing an appropriate number of lines, and passing them to the thread-pool to handle.  That will allow you to queue up an arbitrarily large number of jobs, and the pending-jobs-queue will be drained as quickly as possible by an appropriately smaller number of thread-pool-threads (e.g. you could have a thread-count equal to the number of cores in the machine you are running on)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want this. Feel free to replace the std:: mechanisms below with their Qt equivalent (QString vs std::string, etc...)

```
struct Job
{
   std::string inputFileName;
   std::string outputFileName;
};

std::queue<Job> jobs;

// not shown - populate jobs with the input/output names of files you want to manage

std::mutex m;

unsigned int nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
vector<std::thread> threads;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
    std::thread t = [&m, &jobs] {

        while (true) {
            Job job;
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m); // acquire the lock that protects jobs
                if jobs.empty() {
                    return;  // the queue is empty, this thread can exit
                }
                job = jobs.front();
                jobs.pop();
            }
        
            // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
            // Open the file job.inputFileName and read in the contents
            // Open the output file job.outputFileName
            // then do your processing and write to the output file handle
            // close your files

            // all done for this file - loop back to the top of this lambda function and get the next file
        }
    };

    threads.push_back(std::move(t));
}

// wait for all threads to finish
for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```